# What is the difference between the #name and [(ngModel)]="name" in Angular2 Form input?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am a little bit confused, for some tutorial use `#` to get the input, while some use the `[(ngModel)]`. What is the effective difference between the two?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**#xxx**

`#xxx` allows you to get an element reference.

```
<input #inp (change)="foo = inp.value">
```

listenes to the change event and calls `onChange()` and passes the inputs `value` property

For two-way binding you also need

```
<input #inp (change)="foo = inp.value)" [value]="foo = $event">
```

**NgModel**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="foo">
```

uses the `NgModel` directive that allows to integrate DOM input elements and custom components into Angular form functionality.
It can also be used without a form.
`NgModel` is an abstraction over all kinds of elements and components, while above (`#inp`) example only works for input elements that have a `value` property and emit a `change` event.

```
[(ngModel)]="foo"
```

is the short form of

```
[ngModel]="foo" (ngModelChange)="foo = $event"
```

which shows it is for two-way binding.

**hint**

`#xxx` returns a component or directive instance, if the element is not a plain DOM element but an Angular component or has an Angular directive applied.

Answer (score 11):

The #name syntax is a template reference which refers to the html object, more information can be found on in the Angular docs:
[Angular template guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)

The [(ngModel)] is setting two way binding on the elements value and assigning that to a variable.

Answer (score -2):

Template reference variable is only used for accessing the dom properties of the element.
So for two binding or any change we need to write
->
but by using ngmodel binding which  helps in angular two way data binding can be done in a short by :
->

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. Note the markup of the code examples is likely incorrect and needs fixing: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help