# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am actually working on a form and i am doing the validations for each field. but there is an issue. my block of component.html file looks like this,

```
 <div class="field"style="padding:1%">
      <label>Pacs name</label>

      <input 
      name ="name" 
      type="text" 
      [(ngModel)]="pacs.name" 
      formControlName="pacName" 
      required 
      pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+"
      #name="ngModel"
      >

  </div>
```

This is the field i am working on but when i am using #name="ngModel" i am getting this error in browser.

there is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

I placed FormsModule is the respective module.ts file. and my respective imports in component.ts file looks like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit,Directive, forwardRef, 
  Attribute,OnChanges, SimpleChanges,Input  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,NG_VALIDATORS,Validator,
  AbstractControl,ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,FormControl, Validators, Form, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
```

I think there could be versioning problem,

so my versions are,
Angular CLI: 1.7.0
Node: 6.11.4
OS: linux x64

Could someone please help ? i am not understanding where is the exact problem.

Answer (score 7):

On one hand, you use reactive API linking this control to the explicitly created model property from your TS code: `formControlName="pacName"`. On the other, you're trying to bind to the never-created implicit model from the template-driven API: `#name="ngModel"` and `name="name"`.

In the template driven API you could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" ngModel #name="ngModel">
```

Just remove `#name="ngModel"` and `name="name"` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference your input element in component i.e. a custom control/child control then you can give it a reference name with #nameofcontrol

Check this answer : [what is the difference between the #name and [(ngModel)]="name" in Angular2 Form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234559/what-is-the-difference-between-the-name-and-ngmodel-name-in-angular2-form)